# Php Excel Reader - Get Background Colours

Tags: php, excel

I am using phpexcelreader:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

And It is working nicely compared to all the others I tried, But I am struggling to find a way to get background colors of the cells, or any color formatting to be honest.

Does anyone know of how to do this with this class, or, how to add it into this class?

It can't be too hard, surely?

Comment: Love it when somebody adds "It can't be too hard, surely?" at the end of their question

Comment: Glad I bring joy to your life, Baker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `$data` is the phpExcelReader object you can use:

```
$data->bgColor($row,$col,$sheet=0);
```

which is returned in `#FFFFFF` format.

I think you can find some good docs here: http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/wiki/Documentation

From user comments, the updated syntax is:

```
$bgcolor = $xls->colors[$xls->bgColor($y,$x,$sheet)];
```

which is not covered in the docs.

Comment: The bgcolor function didnt work, neither could I find it in the class. However I found the .ZIP version from the link you sent me, and that works perfectly, straight away.  Thanks, I will use that from now on.  Strange, I tried lots of different versions including that one, for some reason all the ones I downloaded didnt work at all.  I dont think I ever found the version 2.21 though.

Comment: @Chud37 I am guessing you had an old version of the file?

Comment: for some reason though, I dont get a hex value when running: `$sheet = 8;
  $col = $xls->bgColor($y,$x,$sheet)` like 8 or 51 or something.  Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Chud37 Not sure to be honest, I was thinking of forking the project and seeing if I can update it, but haven't really used it much. Sorry.

Comment: found it. had to read through the $data->style class to get it though, documentation wasnt up to date: `$bgcolor = $xls->colors[$xls->bgColor($y,$x,$sheet)];`

Comment: @Chud37 THanks mate, I have updated the answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Fluffeh, has got a good point. I assume the problem is in the version of `php-excel-reader` you downloaded, it is sure out of date or it is prior the version 2.2.

[image]

So go to https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list and download the latest version to get that function in production. :)

Also in the version 2.21 it looks like this:

[image: ver 2.21 of excel_reader2.php]

Also in the version 2.2 it looks like this:

[image: ver 2.2 of excel_reader2.php]

I hope it will help also somebody :). Happy programming.